# Vitest defineConfig, 'test' does not exist in type 'UserConfigExport'

Tags: typescript, vite, vitest

Trying to setup vitest on an already existing vite (vue 3, typescript) project.

My vite.config.ts looks like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
});
```

But in VS code it complains:

[image: vscode red lines under test prop]

On hover I see:

> Argument of type '{ test: { globals: boolean; environment: string; }; plugins: Plugin[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserConfigExport'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'test' does not exist in type 'UserConfigExport'.ts(2345)

I can make it go away if I change this line:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
```

To:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
```

But why? What's up with this? Why should I have to import defineConfig from vitest in order to get it to support the test property?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Because this is how TypeScript works. Vite config interface does not know anything about Vitest and TS does not allow excessive properties (properties not defined by the type/interface)

---

Because Vite itself does not know anything about Vitest and it's configuration. So Vitest must [extend](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/blob/main/packages/vitest/src/config.ts) Vite config (defined as TS interface)

In order to use this extended interface (instead of the original one), you must first import it.

So instead of doing this (importing pure Vite config):

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
```

do this (importing Vite config extended by Vitest):

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
```

Alternatively you can also use a "tripple slash command" as documented in [Configuring Vitest](https://vitest.dev/config/)

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    // ...
  },
})
```

Comment: not working for me

Comment: Neither for me, but this answer did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73106019/1408053

Comment: This worked for me after I upgraded vite to 4.0.4, and vitest to 0.26.3

Comment: I was already using the triple slash but didn't work.
as @DavidHorm mentioned upgrading vite to 4.0.4 solved the issue for me :D

Comment: Added the /// reference and the error went away for me. Thanks

Comment: If it doesn't work, It's probably because vite and vitest are incompatible with each other. To verify this you can upgrade both libs to the latest version and see if the tsc error disappears. If that's the case you need to either upgrade vite or downgrade vitest

Comment: Didn't work for me but separating config by having vite.config.ts and vitest.config.ts helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75020580/837165.

Comment: thanks @LorenzoRivosecchi i updated vite and it works with directive

Comment: Thanks a lot, also can be use in `tsconfig.node.json`, by add `"types": ["vitest"]` to it. :+1:

Answer (score 19):

Here is what I did in case someone is still looking for a solution. I created my own type and extended to `UserConfig`.

```
...
import type { InlineConfig } from 'vitest';
import type { UserConfig } from 'vite';

interface VitestConfigExport extends UserConfig {
  test: InlineConfig;
}
...
```

Then I casted the type of `config` object to my custom interface -

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [solidPlugin()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  test: {
    environment: 'jsdom',
    globals: true,
    transformMode: {
      web: [/\.[jt]sx?$/],
    },
    setupFiles: './setupVitest.ts',
  },
  build: {
    target: 'esnext',
  },
} as VitestConfigExport);
```

This also enabled intellisense for new `test` property. Also, you don't need to declare `/// <reference types="vitest" />`. It might help.

Comment: works with nuxt3, thanks

Comment: Note that using `as` means that type-checking is entirely circumvented and you won't get type errors if anything in your object structure is incorrect. Ideally, use `satisfies`.

Answer (score 19):

I separated the files because i got the from this question and if i changed the import to vitest i got another error in the plugin react line.

- vite.config.ts
- vitest.config.ts

vitest:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

    export default defineConfig({
        test: {
          globals: true,
          environment: 'jsdom'
        },
      })
```

vite:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
})
```

Comment: This feels like the most elegant solution of the ones posted here.

Answer (score 16):

I was in a similar situation, asking me the same thing and end up doing this:

```js
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import type { UserConfig as VitestUserConfigInterface } from 'vitest/config';

const vitestConfig: VitestUserConfigInterface = {
  test: {
    // vitest config, with helpful vitest typing :)
  }
};

export default defineConfig({
  test: vitestConfig.test,
  // and now: just vite config
});
```

It may be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

[sunny prakash solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74453402/4357871) is quite good, but it allow wrong type in config due to `as VitestConfigExport` construction.

Better way is to move config to separate constant and use it

```
import type { InlineConfig } from 'vitest';
import type { UserConfig } from 'vite';

type ViteConfig = UserConfig & { test: InlineConfig };
const config: ViteConfig = {
  // other config
  test: {
    environment: 'jsdom',
  },
};
export default defineConfig(config);
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `mergeConfig` method from `vite` or `vitest/config` entries to merge Vite config with Vitest config:

```
import { defineConfig as defineViteConfig, mergeConfig } from 'vite';
import { defineConfig as defineVitestConfig } from 'vitest/config';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

const viteConfig = defineViteConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
});

const vitestConfig = defineVitestConfig({
  test: {
    // ...
  },
});

export default mergeConfig(viteConfig, vitestConfig);
```

Comment: This works, makes sense, really wish we didn't have to do it, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

None of the options listed above helped me. Eventually, I've managed to solve this issue using the type augmentation feature:

```
import type { UserConfig as VitestUserConfig } from 'vitest/config';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

declare module 'vite' {
  export interface UserConfig {
    test: VitestUserConfig['test'];
  }
}

export default defineConfig({
  // add your vite configuration here

  test: {
    // add your vitest configuration here
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue that was resolved by using a version of vitest and vite that were compatible. In my case the latest version of each. I assume using versions that were released around the same time frame would work as well.

```bash
yarn install -D vitest vite
```

Answer (score 1):

The above method doesn't work for me, then I try this, It work.

```html
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'; // 支持jsx语法

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(() => {
  return {
    plugins: [vue(), vueJsx()],
    test: {
      globals: true,
      environment: 'jsdom',
      transformMode: { web: [/.[tj]sx$/] },
    },
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the function with an arrow function worked for me. Mentioned at https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/discussions/1106#discussioncomment-2531279

```
export default defineConfig(() => ({
  build: {
    // ...
  },
  test: {
    // ...
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

as 2024 you can just import vitest/config which pulls the extended types automatically

```
import {defineConfig} from "vite";
import "vitest/config" // <-- just dummy import

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    // your stuff here
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have multiple versions of vite installed. Search in your package-lock or yarn-lock file to find the entries for vite, and make sure there's only one of them. After that, I got it to work using the triple-slash.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue with my project, but after adding `/// <reference types="vitest" />` this line at the top of the file, the error is gone.

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  ...
  test: {
   ...
  },
});
```

Comment: This comment brings no value. It's the same as what the previous post states as an alternative option, and it is apparent from the comments bellow it that for some it works and for some, it doesn't.