# 'test' does not exist in type 'UserConfigExport', even with reference types

Tags: typescript, vite, vitest

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72149404/11790686) and in [the docs](https://vitest.dev/config/). I've added the reference types for Vitest at the top of my Vite config file.

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
```

Why am I still getting the TypeScript warning `'test' does not exist in type 'UserConfigExport'`?

Comment: Hard to tell. What gives you the warning? VS Code or TSC? Did you try to restart IDE? Or try alternative solution - `import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';`

Comment: Thanks, using `defineConfig` from `vitest/config` fixes the problem with `test: {...}`, but introduces problems in other areas (.e.g `'polyfillDynamicImport' does not exist in type 'BuildOptions'`). Multiple IDE's give me the same warning even after restart.

Comment: Maybe version mismatch between Vite and Vitest ?

Answer (score 5):

I have found a workaround for this problem - creating separate `vitest.config.ts` file. As [docs](https://vitest.dev/config/#configuration) states:

> Create `vitest.config.ts`, which will have the higher priority and will override the configuration from `vite.config.ts`

Now you will have intellisense for `test` option.

Example `vitest.config.ts` file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

export default defineConfig({
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'jsdom',
        coverage: {
            provider: 'istanbul', // or 'c8',
            all: true,
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: You deserve a star

Comment: I did it the same way, however it worked for me without any issues with single `vite.config.ts` before, but then I tried moving the project to **monorepo** with **pnpm workspaces** and then the issue appeared, I don't understand why though. If someone has an idea, let me know please.

Answer (score 4):

I defined my own type and extended it to `UserConfig`.

```
...
import type { InlineConfig } from 'vitest';
import type { UserConfig } from 'vite';

interface VitestConfigExport extends UserConfig {
  test: InlineConfig;
}
...
```

Then I casted the type of `config` object to my custom interface -

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [solidPlugin()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  test: {
    environment: 'jsdom',
    globals: true,
    transformMode: {
      web: [/\.[jt]sx?$/],
    },
    setupFiles: './setupVitest.ts',
  },
  build: {
    target: 'esnext',
  },
} as VitestConfigExport);
```

This also enabled intellisense for new `test` property. Also, you don't need to define `/// <reference types="vitest" />`.