# Ionic 7 React Typescript default eslint settings prevents VSCode from displaying missing dependancies for useEffect hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, eslint

When i generate a new React Typescript application using the latest version 7 of the Ionic CLI, i am not seeing any `eslint` warnings for missing dependencies in any `useEffect` hooks that i add inside a component when viewing the project in VSCode.

I am using VSCode as my IDE with the ESLint extension installed.

I can confirm that older applications which were generated with version 6 or lower of the Ionic CLI do display warnings and offer a list of suggested dependencies to insert automatically.

Here is what i see in VSCode when viewing an older Ionic 6 application:

[image: Ionic 6.x Example]

And below is what i see in a new Ionic 7 application for the same code, with no warnings:

[image: Ionic 7 Example]

My Ionic 6 app does not have an `eslintrc` configuration file, instead the only configuration i could find was in the package.json file:

```
...
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
...
```

In the Ionic 7 app, the Ionic CLI generated the following `.eslintrc.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'eslint:recommended'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
  }
}
```

I am not well versed in configuring `eslint` to understand how to change or update the configuration that Ionic 7 uses in-order to get VSCode to display the same warnings that i see for the version 6 app and could really use some help.

I did try running `npx eslint --init` from the terminal, followed the prompts and installed the additional packages it suggested i needed but this did not work.

Subsequently, in VSCode, i tried running the command "ESLint: Restart ESLint Server" which did not work to correct the issue.

I also tried running the command "ESLint: Show Output Channel", which shows that ESLint is running without any errors.

Lastly, i tried following [this 2023 guide](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/set-up-eslint-and-prettier-in-a-react-typescript-app-2022-7d9a5f40b634), albeit likely that it was not meant for use in an application that was generated by the Ionic CLI, and needless to say, it was not a perfect fit and i could not get it to work.

Has anyone else run into this problem yet and found a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic 7 uses Vite, and thus after doing some further digging around I was able to solve the problem with some help from [this guide](https://www.robinwieruch.de/vite-eslint/)

First, since my app was generated using the Ionic CLI, I skipped the initial part of the guide which outlines installing and configuring `vite-plugin-eslint` and preserved the `vite.config.ts` as it was installed by the CLI.

If i had any issues after proceeding with the rest of the guide i was going to circle back to this and try it if i still had any problems getting ESLint to work.

Instead, first, i just installed the `eslint-config-react-app` package:
`npm install eslint-config-react-app --save-dev`

Then, i executed the ESLint: Show Output Channel command in VSCode to see if i had any issues. Immediately it complained that i needed to specify the react version in settings in my `.eslintrc.js` configuration.

So i updated the `.eslintrc.js` configuration to include the needed `settings` as per the error from the Output Channel and then, as per the Vite guide noted above, i also updated the `extends` section to include `react-app`:

```
  'settings': { // <-- added settings and included react version detect
    'react': {
      'version':'detect',
      }
     },
     'extends': [
       'react-app', // <-- added react-app
       'plugin:react/recommended',
       'eslint:recommended',
     ],
```

Lastly, i restarted the ESLint Server in VSCode.

And, voilà , ESLint lit up like a Christmas tree  with one catch...

Upon doing so, i was seeing only one, new, issue inside `vite.config.ts` whereas TS was complaining that `test` was not a known property on the config. I was able to fix the problem via [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72149404/2934896)

Note, i am still learning about how to correctly configure ESLint so i have yet to find out if i am still missing anything or if i should have done this differently, but with the updates noted, ESLint is working as expected.

I hope this is helpful for anyone that runs into this issue, but please also feel free to comment if anyone feels this approach is wrong or if there is a better way to go about solving the problem.